# Uploadifive not working iOS 8

Tags: iphone, ipad, safari, ios8, uploadifive

Uploadifive version 1.1.2 is not working on iPhone and iPad running iOS 8

Try the demo using iPad or iPhone running iOS 8 at:

http://www.boxorox.net/

Clicking the *Select File* button allows you to choose a file from the mobile device.

Then clicking *Upload Files* does nothing, the upload never starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has now been fixed for Safari in iOS update 8.0.2

Note: uploading is still broken on Chrome running iOS 8.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a new bug on _file_input_ field that was introduced in iOS 8.0.

Since last week Apple has gone ahead and fixed and then reverted it too. I recommend you wait for the iOS 8.0.1 upgrade to be available and then hopefully it will start working again as expected.

Until then, I'm afraid there is very little you could do about it. Here is the stream of [Apple's Web Development](https://twitter.com/xeenon/status/513569772957466624) 
team to give you details about it. Have a good one!